# IB C++ Api reqHistoricalData - TagValueListSPtr

Tags: c++, tws

i want to use the C++ Interactive Brokers API to request historical data.
But the documentation is really bad and i cannot find a example of the Type TagValueListSPtr (last parameter).

```
 contract.symbol="USD";
 contract.secType="CASH";
 contract.currency = "EUR";
 contract.exchange = "IDEALPRO";

 m_pClient->reqHistoricalData(1, contract, "20140920 00:00:00", "1 D", "1 day", "TRADES" 0, 2, ????);
```

the documentation is located here https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/c/reqhistoricaldata.htm

Comment: the type name makes it sound like a shared pointer - can you default construct one to pass in? `TagValueListSPtr()` or `TagValueListSPtr(nullptr)`

Comment: @SteveLorimer, this works - but why ? cannot find this in the documentation :-/

Comment: It might work... it also might blow up if they try to dereference the pointer internally without checking it's valid! By passing a default constructed shared pointer you're essentially passing nothing (if that makes sense). They mention in the docs to pass XYZ. Perhaps there's a variable in global scope with that name? Try searching the source for TagValueListSPtr to see if they provide you with any.